# How do I find out what file Apache is serving when a port is hit?

Tags: linux, centos, apache-httpd, tcp

I'm working on a server someone else set up. The server is CentOS 4.6 running Apache/2.0.59 (httpd). They have an update service setup on port 8443. I know it is working but I need to find out what files Apache is serving when someone hits that port.

I looked in the httpd.conf file to see if there was anything in there but there was nothing there. I tried using `nmap` too but that only showed me which ports are currently open. The output of `nmap` was:

```
8443/tcp open https-alt
```

So how can I find out what files are served when someone connects to that port?

Comment: Can you find it in the log file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can see where `httpd` is configured to look for it's configuration files using the `-V` switch:

```
$ httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb 13 2012 22:31:42
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:24
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

You can also use the command `lsof` to see what files a Unix process is accessing. My version of `httpd` is using the stock port 80 so change the 80 to 8443 in your case!

```
$ netstat -tapn|grep ::80
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      5338/httpd
```

You can now run `lsof` to find out where the log files are getting written to:

```
$ lsof -p 5338|grep log
httpd   5338 root  mem    REG  253,0    10440   3141 /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_logio.so
httpd   5338 root  mem    REG  253,0    27200   3139 /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_log_config.so
httpd   5338 root    2w   REG  253,0     2014 395029 /var/log/httpd/error_log
httpd   5338 root    7w   REG  253,0     4140 394789 /var/log/httpd/access_log
```

You should be able to determine the location of the `access_log` as well as the configuration files and look through them to determine the "Directory" and "Location" directives. These specify what local directories to use when telling Apache what files to serve.

#### Now what?

I would then look through the `access_log` to make sure that there are entries in there that correspond to accesses against the server. What I mean by this is if I browse the server at `http://www.somedom.com/somefile` I should see this access recorded in the `access_log` file like this:

```
192.168.1.110 - - [17/Jul/2013:14:39:50 -0400] "GET /somefile HTTP/1.1" 200 4303 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/5
37.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36"
```

#### Where are the files?

You can take the above knowledge that we've acquired and start to apply it like so:

These bits from `httpd -V` tells us Apache's root:

```
-D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

So we know the main config file is here: `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. So look through that file for these lines:

```
$ grep -E "DocumentRoot|Directory \"|^Include" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf |grep -v "^#"
Include conf.d/*.conf
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www/html">
<Directory "/var/www/icons">
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    <Directory "/var/www/error">
```

So I now know that these directories are potential sources for the file we saw in the `access_log`. The `DocumentRoot` and `Directories` I'd look through for the file, `somefile`. If it isn't in any of these locations then I'd next focus on the `Include` directory mentioned above in the `grep` output, `/etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf`.

These files are additional configurations that Apache uses so you'd need to repeat the steps using the `grep` to look through these files as well.

Comment: Yeah this is way close! This log shows me what users are requesting from the URL but I want to find which file that corresponds to on the server. How can I do that?

Comment: @Aust - See updates.

Comment: You make me so happy! Thanks! The files were not in those original directories so I ran `grep -E "DocumentRoot|Directory \"|^Include" /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf |grep -v "^#"` and started searching through those directories and found it. =D

Comment: @Aust - glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
# netstat -ntaupe | grep 8443
```